# how to dissect string values

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

How can I dissect or retrieve string values?

Here's the sample code that I'm working on now:

```
private void SplitStrings()
{
    List<string> listvalues = new List<string>();
    listvalues = (List<string>)Session["mylist"];
    string[] strvalues = listvalues.ToArray();
    for (int x = 0; x < strvalues.Length; x++)
    {
        
    }

}
```

Now that I'am able to retrieve list values in my session. How can I separately get the values of each list using `foreach` or `for` statement?

What I want to happen is to programmatically split the values of the strings depending on how many is in the list.

Comment: Are you really wanting to *split* a string? Your code only seems to want to loop through an array (and already does so). If the answers are not what you're after, can you clarify?

Comment: could you give us more details about what you want exactly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list of string values, you can do the following:

```
private void SplitStrings()
{
    List<string> listValues = (List<string>) Session["mylist"];

    // always check session values for null
    if(listValues != null)
    {
        // go through each list item
        foreach(string stringElement in listValues)
        {
             // do something with variable 'stringElement'
             System.Console.WriteLine(stringElement);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I test the result of casting the session and that I don't create a new list first-off, which is not necessary. Also note that I don't convert to an array, simply because looping a list is actually easier, or just as easy, as looping an array.

Note that you named your method `SplitStrings`, but we're not splitting anything. Did you mean to split something like "one;two;three;four" in a four-element list, based on the separator character?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to obtain in this code, I don't know why you're converting your `List` to an `Array`.

You can loop through your `listValues` collection with a `foreach` block:

```
foreach(string value in listValues)
{
    //do something with value, I.e.
    Response.Write(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's in the strings but you can start by simplifying. There is no point allocating a new List if you're going to overwrite it immediately.

```
    private void SplitStrings()
    {
        List<string> list = (List<string>)Session["mylist"];

        foreach(string value in list)
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List listvalues = (List)Session["mylist"];
foreach (string s in listvalues)
{
  //do what you want with s here
}
```